# Calculate probability that normal distribution sample is smallest in group polars python

Tags: python, python-polars, normal-distribution

I have a polars dataframe along the lines of:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "mean": [25.5, 25.2, 24.9, 50.5, 55.1, 54.2, 60],
        "std": [2.5, 3.5, 1.7, 10.2, 5.5, 7.8, 20.5],
    }
)
```

For each row we have a mean and standard deviation for a normal distribution. I'd like to add a column which represents the probability that when sampling, that row would have the lowest value in its group.

It is a strict requirement that the column is added with an expression which can be entered into a `with_columns` call.

I was able to write the following:

```
def probability_smallest_in_group(series):
    length = len(series)
    means = series.struct.field("mean").to_numpy()
    stds = series.struct.field("std").to_numpy()
    samples = 100_000
    pos = np.argsort(np.argsort(np.random.normal(means, stds, size=(samples, length))))
    result = (pos == 0).mean(axis=0)
    result = pl.Series(result)
    return result


df = df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(["mean", "std"])
    .apply(probability_smallest_in_group)
    .over("group")
    .alias("probability_smallest_in_group")
)
```

I believe this outputs the correct result (approximately). However, this solution is infeasible due to the real dataframe being several million rows - leading to absurd execution time.

What is a better approach to this problem? Is there a solution which does not involve sampling?

Any help is very much appreciated so thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is the correct forum for this question.  This really is a statistics question with a mathematical solution, and you. just happen to be coding in Python.

Comment: @FrankYellin I generally see where you're coming from but I think that would be a duplicate question at either the stats or math SE site.

Answer (score 0):

You can theoretically do this without sampling but since the normal distribution can only be integrated numerically, it turns out that simulations are the least CPU intensive way. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/74117/24521) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/44142/24521).

<s>That being said, you can improve upon your method by making a ufunc with
[numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator) that doesn't require saving the entire matrix of random numbers and it also avoids using [`apply`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.apply.html#polars.Expr.apply) (now, [`map_elements`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_elements.html#polars-expr-map-elements)) which is known for being slow because it just creates a python loop.</s>

The numba version is very similar to what you have except that you'll see we're manually looping where you previously had numpy vectorization. <s>That is ok because</s> it will be compiled before you use it but is [because numba doesn't support the size argument](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#standard-ufuncs).

Here it is:

```
import numba as nb
@nb.guvectorize([(nb.float64[:], nb.float64[:],  nb.float64[:])], 
'(n),(n)->(n)', 
nopython=True)
def prob(means, sds, res):
    width=len(means)
    samples=100_000
    lowest=np.zeros(width)
    for _ in range(samples):
        currand= np.empty(width)
        for j in range(width):
            currand[j] = np.random.normal(means[j], sds[j])
        lowest[np.argsort(currand)[0]] += 1
    for i in range(width):
        res[i]=lowest[i]/samples
```

Unlike a traditional UDF, a [ufunc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/numpy/) can be called directly in a context against expressions and doesn't need apply or map_* so once you define it, you can just do

```
df.with_columns(
    probability_smallest_in_group =prob(pl.col('mean'),pl.col('std')).over('group')
    )
shape: (7, 4)
┌───────┬──────┬──────┬───────────────────────────────┐
│ group ┆ mean ┆ std  ┆ probability_smallest_in_group │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---                           │
│ i64   ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64                           │
╞═══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════════════════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 25.5 ┆ 2.5  ┆ 0.27643                       │
│ 1     ┆ 25.2 ┆ 3.5  ┆ 0.37609                       │
│ 1     ┆ 24.9 ┆ 1.7  ┆ 0.34748                       │
│ 2     ┆ 50.5 ┆ 10.2 ┆ 0.39728                       │
│ 2     ┆ 55.1 ┆ 5.5  ┆ 0.13646                       │
│ 2     ┆ 54.2 ┆ 7.8  ┆ 0.20896                       │
│ 2     ┆ 60.0 ┆ 20.5 ┆ 0.2573                        │
└───────┴──────┴──────┴───────────────────────────────┘
```

Hmm, well I created the following df to test the timing and the ufunc is slower so I'm not sure where the bottleneck is:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": np.random.choice(125,500),
        "mean": np.random.normal(20,5, size=500),
        "std": abs(np.random.normal(2,5, size=500)),
    }
)
```

Comment: I'm uncertain if it is correct to say that you should take the product. Notice that your probabilities do not sum to 1 across groups.